# Can the bar labels appear centered on the appropriate bar in a combine bar/line graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Using the following data frame:

```
day <- c("Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat","Sun","Week","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat","Sun","Week")
day <- factor(day, level=c("Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat","Sun","Week"))
month<-c("Jan","Jan","Jan","Jan","Jan","Jan","Jan","Jan","Feb","Feb","Feb","Feb","Feb","Feb","Feb","Feb")
month<-factor(month,level=c("Jan","Feb"))
snow<-gl(1,16,labels=c("Y"))
snow<-factor(snow,levels=c("Y","N"))
count <- c(4,5,6,8,3,4,9,5.57,2,4,3,7,1,9,3,4.14)
d <- data.frame(day=day,count=count,month=month,snow=snow)
```

The bar labels center over week instead of the correct month's bar:

```
ggplot()+geom_line(data=d[d$day!="Week",],aes(x=day, y=count, group=month, colour=month))+geom_bar(data=d[d$day=="Week",],aes(x=day, y=count, fill=month),position="dodge", group=month)+facet_wrap(~snow,ncol=1,scales="free")+scale_x_discrete(limits=levels(d$day))+geom_text(data=d[d$day=="Week",],aes(x=day, y=count,label=paste(month),vjust=1.5),position="dodge",size=3)
```

Can the month labels appear centered on the appropriate bar?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_text` needs a specific dodge size to work:

```
p <- ggplot(data=d[d$day=="Week",], aes(x=day , y=count, fill=month)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", width = 0.8, stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=month, x=day, y=count), position=position_dodge(width=0.8), vjust=-.6, size=3) + 
  geom_line(data=d[d$day!="Week",], aes(x=day, y=count, group=month, colour=month)) + 
  facet_wrap(~snow,ncol=1,scales="free") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=levels(d$day))
p
```

[image: Fixed graph]

Comment: Thanks!  This was exactly what I looking to achieve.  I'd vote you up, but I'm not at that point yet on this site.

Comment: You can select this answer as *the* answer with the green checkmark, though :)

Comment: You defined several values within ggplot() and then used stat="identity" in geom_bar, which then correctly referenced the labels in geom_text.  For those of you that might make the same mistake as me, just note that the code that I originally used didn't define anything within ggplot() and caused geom_text to malfunction (without throwing an error).

Comment: ggplot yells at you if you leave off `stat="identity"` and will eventually deprecate any histogram-like calls without it. And you don't necessarily need to define things in `ggplot()` initially… anything defined in the `aes=` section of the initial call gets used in all other layers (like `geom_bar` and `geom_text`)—putting the data in the initial call prevents duplication, but you can still make the graph without it.